# require to form a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was working on preparing a query where I was stuck.

Consider tables below:

table1

```
id key col1
-- --- -----
 1  1   abc
 2  2   d
 3  3   s
 4  4   xyz
```

table2

```
id col1 foreignkey
-- ---- ----------
1   12    1
2   13    1
3   14    1
4   12    2
5   13    2
```

Now what I need is to select only those records from `table1` for which the corresponding entries in `table2` does not have say `col1` value as `12`.
So the challenge is after applying `join` even though it will skip for value 1 corresponding to `col1` equal to `12` it still has another multiple rows whose values are say `13`, `14` for which also they have same `foreignkey`. Now what I want is if there is a single row having value `12` then it should not pick that id at all from `table1`.

How can I form a query with this?

The output which i need is say from above table structure i want to get those records from table1 for which col1 value from table2 does not have value as 14.
so my query should return me only row 2 from table1 and not row 1.

Comment: please Give desire Output..

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical case for `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id, [key], col1
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.foreignkey = t1.id AND t2.col1 = 14)
```

The above query will not select a row from `table1` if there is a single correlated row in `table2` having `col1 = 14`.

**Output:**

```
id  key col1
-------------
2   2   d
3   3   s
4   4   xyz
```

If you want to return records that, in addition to the criterion set above, also have correlated records in `table2`, then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.id, MAX(t1.[key]) AS [key], MAX(t1.col1) AS col1
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.foreignkey
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.col1 = 14 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

**Output:**

```
id  key col1
-------------
2   2   d
```

You can also achieve the same result with the second query using a combination of `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id, [key], col1
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table2 t2
              WHERE t2.foreignkey = t1.id) 
      AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2 t3
                  WHERE t3.foreignkey = t1.id AND t3.col1 = 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing that. The first two queries are just for making the sample data.

```
;WITH t1(id ,[key] ,col1) AS
(
 SELECT 1 , 1 ,  'abc' UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 , 2  , 'd' UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 , 3  , 's' UNION ALL
 SELECT 4 , 4  , 'xyz'
 )
 ,t2(id ,col1, foreignkey) AS
(
SELECT 1  , 12   , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2  , 13   , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3  , 14   , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4   ,12   , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 5   ,13  ,  2
)
SELECT id, [key], col1
FROM t1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT t2.Id
                 FROM t2
                 INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.Id = t2.foreignkey
                 WHERE t2.col1 = 14)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select t1.id,t1.key,
(select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1 DESC) AS Row,* into
 #Temp from table1)
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.foreignkey
where t2.col1=(select col1 from #temp where row>1)
```